# NGINX config for subdirectory website CMS doesn't removes /index.php/

Tags: docker, nginx, url-rewriting

My current NGINX config to hosting a website in a subdirectory on a Docker server doesn't seem to work. I tried several things but nothing concluding.

```
server {
    root /www;
    access_log /logs/access.log;
    error_log /logs/error.log debug;
    index index.html index.php;
    if ($bad_referer) { return 444; }

    # Enable PHP with path_info for any php subfolder
    location ~ ^(.+\.php)($|/) {
        fastcgi_pass archives_php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include /nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }


    ###
    ### SPECIFIC SITE
    ###
    # Cockpit
    location = /site { try_files $uri /site/index.php$uri?$args; }
    location /site {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site/index.php$uri?$args;
        location ~ ^(.+\.php)($|/) {
            fastcgi_pass archives_php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include /nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    location /site/cockpit { try_files $uri $uri/ /site/cockpit/index.php; }


    # Assets disabled logging and expiration max
    include /nginx/assets.conf;
}

# Anti spam referrals
include /nginx/referral-spam.conf;
```

The website works when using `dubsomain.site.com/site/index.php/page` but this is not the behaviour I would like to have.

A similar website with the same CMS but in the root folder works like a charm.

Comment: If you append `$uri` to `index.php` you get `/site/index.php/site/page`. Is that the problem, removing `/site` from the path info?

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried to remove the $uri in the index but it doesn't seem to change much. Currently the site works as `https://sub.domain.com/site/index.php/pagename` but not `https://sub.domain.com/site/pagename` for some reason.

Comment: What he's getting at is that it's probably that you need to work on configuring re-write rules

Answer (score 0):

If you need to append part of the URI to `/site/index.php`, you will need to use a regular expression.

For example:

```
location /site {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/site(.*)$ /site/index.php$1 last;
}
```

The `location = /site` is unnecessary, unless there is a specific action that URI needs to perform, and your second `location ~ ^(.+\.php)($|/)` block which is nested within the `location /site` block is never invoked, and being identical, is unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to fix the `/page` and other `/page/subpage` links but not the homepage one. I don't really understand because when the site was online on a domain it was fine with the default config proved by the CMS, but now on a subfolder it's a proper mess.